# Need to call a single instance of a class

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have this project that is broken up into different classes. There is a collection class involved called Fields (using the generic BindingList class to hold Field classes), Field (a simple class needed to hold some properties), and various Form classes (basically for each 'tab' of the Form I'm working on).

I have a few functions I call to basically add new Field classes to the Fields class. I only want one instance of the Fields class so I can keep track of all the Field classes within. I'm also wanting to use this single instance of Fields to be a datasource for a ListBox.

My problem is that it seems like I'm not actually using a single instance for my functions, so I keep creating new binding lists (which is definitely not what I want).

I've looked a bit into attempting to create a singleton class, or creating a module. It hasn't worked for me so far so currently I have the instance as a public property `Public Shared FieldsInstance As New Fields`. I figure this is where I'm going wrong. I'm afraid I may be creating a new instance everytime I call this. This is probably the problem, I just don't know the right solution. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Here is what I have in my binding list class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Fields
Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of Field)
Implements IBindingList, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICancelAddNew, IRaiseItemChangedEvents

' Public property of the class that functions as the access of the single instance
Public Shared FieldsInstance As New Fields

' Constructor is protected so it can't be called
Protected Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared Function fnInitializeFields()
    fnInitializeFields = New Fields
Return fnInitializeFields
End Function

Public Sub fnFindByName(ByRef oPassedField As Field)

    Dim oField As New Field
    oField = oPassedField
    If FieldsInstance.Contains(oField) = False Then
        FieldsInstance.Add(oField)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Field already exists!")

End Sub
```

Here is my other class calling the functions based on 2 events. One when form loads and the other when I click on an item in another listbox.

```
Imports BatchImportApplication.Fields
Public Class Form

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Form loads for the first time

    ' Initializes an instance of the Fields class
    Fields.fnInitializeFields()

Private Sub lstSTHFields_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As    EventArgs) Handles lstSTHFields.SelectedIndexChanged

' STH Field is selected

    ' Checks to see if object exists, if not it gets created
    Dim oField As New Field
        oField.sName = lstSTHFields.SelectedItem
        FieldsInstance.fnFindByName(oField)
```

Here is the Field class just in case:

```
Public Class Field
Public Property sName As String
Public Property sCurrent As String
Public Property cDelimiter As Char
Public Property sDefault As String

' Basic Constructor

Public Sub New()
    sName = "new"
    sCurrent = ""
    cDelimiter = ":"
    sDefault = ""
End Sub

Public Sub New(Name As String)
    sName = Name
    sCurrent = ""
    cDelimiter = ":"
    sDefault = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered!

For starters, your `fnInitializeFields` is useless because you are creating a new instance of Fields when you call that, but you already have an instance of fields
`Public Shared FieldsInstance As New Fields`
You also don't assign `fnInitializeFields` return value to anything anyway, so it is just a wasted call that does nothing.
The other problem is in your `fnFindByName` sub. You are creating a new instance of field in that selectedindexchanged event, and then passing that to your `fnFindByName` function. Then you are relying on the `.Contains()` method to look for duplicates. Well contains is going to do an object comparison. This means it is only going to return true when you pass in the exact same object instance of a field class, not just one that happens to have the same sName value. That means it will never tell me that "Field already exists!"

Try this:

```
Public Class Fields
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of Field)

' Public property of the class that functions as the access of the single instance
Public Shared FieldsInstance As New Fields

' Constructor is protected so it can't be called
Protected Sub New()
End Sub


Public Sub fnFindByName(oPassedField As Field)

    Dim DupFound As Boolean = False
    For Each F As Field In FieldsInstance
        If F.sName = oPassedField.sName Then
            'NAME ALREADY EXISTS
            DupFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not DupFound Then
        FieldsInstance.Add(oPassedField)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Field already exists!")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```